# How to replace an integer element in a 2d array with a string type, using a Random

Tags: java, arrays, string, random

I have this table (2d array) and I'm using a Random utility from numbers 0-4 to select a row and column to replace a number with the letter "P" and I have everything but I get this.

```
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from String 
     to int
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from 
     Random to int
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from 
     Random to int
```

Meanwhile this question [How to change value of array element in 2D arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530380/how-to-change-value-of-array-element-in-2d-arrays) says you can just do

```
someArray[row][column] = "x";
```

Here is what I have (I assume my problem is with using the random)

```
import java.util.Random;
    public class Server{
            private int number;
            private boolean pennyLanded;
             public Server()
            {
                 int n = 0;
                 number = n;
                 pennyLanded = false;
            }
             public boolean pennyLanded()
            {
               return pennyLanded;
            }
             public void setPennyLanded()
            {
               pennyLanded = true;
            }
             public int getNumber()
            {
               return number;
            }
             public String toString()
            {
               if (pennyLanded)
                  return "P";
               else
                  return "" + number;
            }
        public static int[][] tableMaker(){
            int[][] table = new int[5][5];
            for(int i=0; i<table.length; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<table.length; j++){
                    if(i==2 && j==2){
                        table[i][j] =3;
                    }
                    else if(i==0 || i==4){
                        table[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                    else if(j==4 || j==0){
                        table[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                    else if((i==1 || i==3) && (j>0 || j<4)){
                        table[i][j] = 2;
                    }
                    else if((i==2 && j==1) || (i==2 && j==3)){
                        table[i][j] = 2;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i<table.length; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<table.length; j++){
                    System.out.print(table[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            return table;
        }



        public static int[][] tossPenny(){
            Random row = new Random();
            Random column = new Random();
            int[][] table = Server.tableMaker();
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                table[row.nextInt(4)][column.nextInt(4)] = -1;
            }
            return table;
        }

    }
```

The table is printed in a Client class

```
public class Client{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(Server.tableMaker());
    }
}
```

I Don't know how simple of a fix this is, and I have searched I just have a particular problem

The table is printed as so

```
1 1 1 1 1 
1 2 2 2 1 
1 2 3 2 1 
1 2 2 2 1 
1 1 1 1 1
```

And I would like something like this say the random puts out 1 and 2

```
1 1 1 1 1 
1 2 P 2 1 
1 2 3 2 1 
1 2 2 2 1 
1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Integer.valueOf method. Look into that. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: There are a few problems with this.  One of the main ones is that you're trying to assign a `String` variable into a 2D array of `int`.  You should either use a 2D array of `String`, and convert all the numbers before putting them in; or use a special `int` value (such as -1 for example) to represent the penny.  There are other problems too, but this should get you started.

Comment: Yeah I have a [[I@690aefdb problem that needs to be fixed but I'm trying to ignore that for now until I can get the actual thing working thanks though

Comment: @DavidWallace Now I would just use 2 FOR loops to check for -1s and replace with Ps? Also I would gladly accept your answer if you posted it instead of a comment

Comment: That's the whole point - if you've got an `int[][]` you _can't_ put "P" in it.  What you need to do (if you use that solution) is check what to print, _when_ you print it out.  So your output method will have some logic that says "if it's -1, print P, otherwise print the number".  And the reason why I didn't post an answer is because there are _other_ things wrong with your code, that I haven't dealt with, and I don't believe in posting an answer that doesn't actually fully work.

Comment: @DavidWallace Okay so I made the following constructor         `public String toString()
        {
           if (pennyLanded)
              return "P";
           else
              return "" + number;
        }` But now I'm confused as how to apply it without redoing my entire code

Comment: OK, that's not a constructor; that's a method.  Which class did you put it in?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say I created that using a constructor "pennylanded" and I'll update my code I put it in the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure it out with help of a IRL friend and this avoids the memory store errors as seen before, Server is below

```
 import java.util.Random;
    public class Server{
    private static int[][] table;
    public static int[][] tableMaker(){
            table = new int[5][5];
            for(int i=0; i<table.length; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<table.length; j++){
                    if(i==2 && j==2){
                        table[i][j] =3;
                    }
                    else if(i==0 || i==4){
                        table[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                    else if(j==4 || j==0){
                        table[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                    else if((i==1 || i==3) && (j>0 || j<4)){
                        table[i][j] = 2;
                    }
                    else if((i==2 && j==1) || (i==2 && j==3)){
                        table[i][j] = 2;
                    }
                }
            }
            return table;
        }

        public static void printTable(){
            for(int i=0; i<table.length; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<table.length; j++){
                     if(table[i][j] == -1) System.out.print("P ");
                     else System.out.print(table[i][j] + " "); 
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }



        public static int[][] tossPenny(){
            Random row = new Random();
            Random column = new Random();
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                table[row.nextInt(4)][column.nextInt(4)] = -1;
            }
            return table;
        }

    }
```

Client is here

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Client{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Server.tableMaker();
        Server.printTable();
        System.out.println();
        Server.tossPenny();
        Server.printTable();
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot everyone especially @DavidWallace You helped me get around most of my problems and I was able to fix everything using the `private static int[][] table;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `row.nextInt(int max)` instead of row, where the generated random integer `n` is `0 <= n < max`. The parameter of `new Random()` only defines a seed, so I suggest you not use a constant number there unless you want your random algorithm to be deterministic.
Furthermore you mixes up the types a bit. `tableMaker()` should be `String[][]` in order to write Strings into it and `tossPenny()` should be `void` since it doesn't return anything.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Server {
    public static String[][] tableMaker() {
        String[][] table = new String[5][5];
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < table.length; j++) {
                if (i == 2 && j == 2) {
                    table[i][j] = "" + 3; // Converting int 3 to String "3"
                } else if (i == 0 || i == 4) {
                    table[i][j] = "" + 1;
                } else if (j == 4 || j == 0) {
                    table[i][j] = "" + 1;
                } else if ((i == 1 || i == 3) && (j > 0 || j < 4)) {
                    table[i][j] = "" + 2;
                } else if ((i == 2 && j == 1) || (i == 2 && j == 3)) {
                    table[i][j] = "" + 2;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < table.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(table[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return table;
    }

    public static void tossPenny(int a) {
        Random row = new Random();
        Random column = new Random();
        String Penny = "P";
        String[][] table = Server.tableMaker();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            table[row.nextInt(5)][column.nextInt(5)] = Penny;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you post an answer that doesn't even compile?

Comment: @DavidWallace Why does it not. What is the exact error. Because I can't imagine why it wouldn't compile unless you tried to compile this code snippet on its own.

Comment: Well, if you had actually TRIED compiling your answer before you posted it, you'd know what the problem is.

Comment: @DavidWallace OK I see. It fixes only one of the errors of the original code.

Comment: So, you've tested it this time?

Comment: @DavidWallace Of course. It does compile now and adds `"P"` up to 5 times to the array. Besides that this method is useless since you neither get a return value nor side effects you can run it now.

Comment: ... and the pennies don't always end up in the same five spots?

Comment: I see you have fixed the final bug; I didn't notice when you did it.  I assume you have tested it now, so I have removed my downvote.